# Why isn't my command button working?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 3.5, Glassfish 3.1.2, and Java EE. I'm trying to create a page that creates a "question" in a table. I have a data table that contains the "answers" that are for the user to select when they try to answer the question.

Being a multiple choice trivia quiz, they need to have one or more of the answer to be correct, and the rest to be right. I'm allowing for there to be 2-6 answers per question, and to have as many as 4 right. So I have a p:dataTable element holding the answers, and I have 3 commandButtons that add, remove, or edit the answers in the table, each of which has a server side method that is ran on click. However, none of the methods run. There is no error nor exception just nothing works.

Here is my page (I'm including the entire page just in case I have an error somewhere else):

```
<h:form id="createQForm">
    <h1>Create A Question</h1>
    <p:messages id="msgs"/>  
    <p:selectOneMenu 
        value="#{createQuestionBean.selectedCategory}"  
        id="lstCategory" required="true" >

        <f:selectItems 
            value="#{createQuestionBean.categories}" />
        <p:ajax listener="#{createQuestionBean.onSelectCategory}" 
                update="lstSubCategory" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:selectOneMenu 
        value="#{createQuestionBean.selectedSubCategory}"  
        id="lstSubCategory" required="false">

        <f:selectItem itemLabel="No Sub-Category" 
                      noSelectionOption="true" />

        <f:selectItems 
            value="#{createQuestionBean.subCategories}"/>

    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <h:panelGrid  columns="3">
        <h:outputLabel for="txtQuestion" id="lblQuestion" value="Question: *" />
        <p:inputText value="#{createQuestionBean.entry.question}"
                     id="txtQuestion" required="true" 
                     requiredMessage="You must provide a question"
                     validatorMessage="#{createQuestionBean.QUESTION_VALIDATION_MESSAGE}">
            <f:validateRegex pattern=".*[\s\d\w]"  />
            <p:ajax update="msgQuestion" event="keyup" />
        </p:inputText>
        <p:message for="txtQuestion" id="msgQuestion" display="icon"/> 
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:outputText value="Horizontal: " />  

    <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{createQuestionBean.selectedOptions}">  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Randomizable?" itemValue="randomizable" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Multiple Choice?" itemValue="multichoice" />  
    </p:selectManyCheckbox> 


    <p:fileUpload 
        value="#{createQuestionBean.questionImage}" mode="simple" 
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" 
        label="Select Images (jpg or png)" 
        sizeLimit="2097152" 
        invalidFileMessage="Sorry, only files of type .jpg, .png or .gif are allowed" 
        invalidSizeMessage="Sorry, files are limited in size to 2 Mb"/>
    <p:dataTable 
        id="answersTable" var="answer" style="width: 250px"
        value="#{createQuestionBean.datamodel}"   
        selection="#{createQuestionBean.selectedAnswer}"
        editMode="cell" editable="true"
        selectionMode="single">

        <p:column style="width:75%"> 
            <p:cellEditor >  
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText 
                        value="#{answer.answer.testAnswer}" />
                </f:facet>  
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText 
                        id="modelInput"  
                        style="width: 97%;height: 97%"
                        value="#{answer.answer.testAnswer}"/>
                </f:facet>  
            </p:cellEditor>  
        </p:column>
        <p:column style="width:25%">  
            #{answer.correct ? "Correct" : "Wrong" }  
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <p:commandButton 
            update="answersTable" ajax="true"
            actionListener="#{createQuestionBean.removeSelect}"
            value="Remove Selected -"/>
        <p:commandButton
            update="answersTable" ajax="true"
            actionListener="#{createQuestionBean.setAsCorrect}"
            value="Set Selected As Right"/>
        <p:commandButton 
            update="answersTable" ajax="true"
            value="Add +"
            actionListener="#{createQuestionBean.addAnswer}"/>

    </h:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton
        action="#{createQuestionBean.saveAndStoreEntry()}" />
</h:form>
```

Here are the methods that are called:

```
public void addAnswer() {
    System.out.println("***** CALLED ADD ANSWER");
    answers.add(new QuestionAnswers());
    answers.get(answers.size() - 1).setCorrect(false);
    setIDs();
    //set the data models
    datamodel = new QuestionAnswersDataModel(new ArrayList<QuestionAnswers>(answers));
}

public void removeSelect() {
    System.out.println("***** CALLED REMOVE SELECT");
    if (selectedAnswer == null && !answers.contains(selectedAnswer)) {
        FacesUtils.addErrorMessage(NO_SELECTION_ERROR);
    } else {
        answers.remove(selectedAnswer);
    }
    setIDs();
    //set the data models
    datamodel = new QuestionAnswersDataModel(new ArrayList<QuestionAnswers>(answers));
}

public void setAsCorrect() {
    System.out.println("***** CALLED SET AS CORRECT");
    if (selectedAnswer != null) {
        selectedAnswer.setCorrect(true);
        if (!entry.getMultichoice()) {
            for (QuestionAnswers questionAnswers : answers) {
                if (questionAnswers != selectedAnswer) {
                    questionAnswers.setCorrect(false);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        FacesUtils.addErrorMessage(NO_SELECTION_ERROR);
    }
    setIDs();

    //set the data models
    datamodel = new QuestionAnswersDataModel(new ArrayList<QuestionAnswers>(answers));
}
```

I've added break points in each method to see if it is called, along with System ouputs.

What am I doing wrong? I though maybe it was because I didn't have the AjaxBehaviourEvent in the method calls, but that changed nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what it was. I removed each element, and found out it was with my input text box. I removed the validators on it, and it still didn't work. Then I find out it was using the entity validation (IE, it couldn't be null, or blank) even though I never said any validation was required. Once I had text in the box the methods ran without error.

Comment: Did you try to use commandButton's attribute 'process="@this"'